# SWIFT - How to get the type of an Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, types, generics

i'm writing a generic method who take a Dictionary and a given type in parameters for build an object.

For example, if you make a SOAP request for get a movie and put away the response in Dictionary you can make:

```
var movie : Movie = myGenericMethod(dic : Dictionary, objectToIntrospect : Movie()) as Movie
```

It's work with:

- Simple Object
- Complex Object

But i have a problem if you have an array of object. 
So imagine your movie object contains an Array of Actors...

With reflection, i get all type of my class's attributes.
With this, i build an Array of Any object which contains my types.
For example, an object contained in other object (Actor in a Movie):

```
//All type of attributes of my movie object, at index [i] i have my "Actor" object
var anyType : Any = typesOfProperties[i]

//I cast it in object
var objectType : NSObject = anyType as NSObject

//Dont worry about this method, it's just for get the dictionary
var otherDico : NSDictionary = ConverterUtilities.extractDictionaryFromOtherDictionary(dict, dicoName: property, soapAction: soapAction) as NSDictionary

//I build the Actor object with the data of the dictionary. objectType.self give the Actor type
var propertyObject: NSObject = self.buildAnyObjectWithDictionary(otherDico, soapAction: "", objectToIntrospect:objectType.self) as NSObject

//I set the property Actor in my Movie object (myObjectToReturn)... The "property" parameter is the key 
ConverterUtilities.setPropertyValue(property, value: propertyObject, objectToReturn : myObjectToReturn, isObject : true)
```

It's work perfectly... If i have just one actor in my movie object, the "propertyObject" will be an Actor type, and this cause objectType is an Actor object.

But, if i have an array, i'm redirect in method who treat Array, and my objectType return "Swift._NSSwiftArrayImpl" and my anyType object return "([myproject.Actor])".
I dont need to know this is just an Array, cause i know it. But i need to know that's an Array of **Actor** for build some Actor object dynamicly !

This is what i have for the moment:

```
var objToAdd: NSObject = self.buildAnyObjectWithDictionary(newDic, soapAction: "", objectToIntrospect: Actor()) as NSObject

arraySpecific.append(objToAdd)
```

As you can see, this work perfectly if i hardcode the type. But i need to make it like the previous example ! Like that:

```
var objToAdd: NSObject = self.buildAnyObjectWithDictionary(newDic, soapAction: "", objectToIntrospect: anObjectWithActorType) as NSObject

arraySpecific.append(objToAdd)
```

(Difference between first and second version is the objectToIntrospect parameter)

Do you know how can i use my Any object (contains: ([myproject.Actor]) for build an instance of one Actor ?

I really need ur help for this ! Regards !

PS: sorry for my bad english, i hope u understand me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, i come back on my post cause i found a solution:
i create a master class, and all of my classes herit of this class.

This super-class have a method name getArrayType.

If one of my children-class need to be used with my generic method and if she contain a Array, they need to override the getArrayType.

Like that:

```
override func getArrayType(anyType : Any) -> String {
    var className = " "
    if(anyType as? NSObject == rows){
        className = Properties.PROJECT_NAME + ".SimpleRow"
    }
    return className
}
```

And i call this method like that (TObject is my super-class):

```
var className = (objectToIntrospect as TObject).getArrayType(anyType)
var obj: AnyClass! = NSClassFromString(className)
```

This work perfectly, but you need to override a method. I hope this help u if u got the same problem !